# React navigation- Wrap button in TabBar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

I'm new in React Native and i'm trying to do the TabBar in the image. My problem is to put a button in the tabbar. If someone can help me or have an idea to create this tabbar it could be really nice.
THX

[image: TabBar example]

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) articles.

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check 
this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig). One of the props to pass TabNavigator is `tabBarComponent`. If you do not want the default styling or have to make custom tabBar you can specify the how the component should look.

In your case this should work.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import {TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Tab1Screen from '../components/tab1Screen';
import Tab2Screen from '../components/tab2Screen';

var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

const mainRoutes = TabNavigator({
 Tab1: {screen: Tab1Screen},
 Tab2: {screen: Tab2Screen}
},
{
 tabBarComponent:({navigation}) => (
  <View style={{flex: 0.1, borderColor: 'green', borderWidth: 1}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center', paddingTop: 15}}>
      <View style={{width: 40, height: 40, borderRadius: 20, borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 1, position: 'absolute', left: width/2.5, bottom:13 }}></View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Tab1')}>
        <Text>Tab1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Tab2')}>
        <Text>Tab2</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>
)});

export default mainRoutes;
```

[image]

Comment: Have you try this on device? I've your code and it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar. I'm using React Navigation v5 and in my case, the button had to execute a custom action instead of navigating to a tab. So this is what I did:

```js
import styles from './styles';
// Other needed imports...

// ...

<Tab.Screen
  name="Add Recipe"
  component={() => null}
  options={{
    tabBarButton: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.addIconWrapper}
        onPress={() => {
          // Your custom action here
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.addIconBackground}>
          <Image source={assets.add} style={styles.addIconImage} />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  }}
/>;
```

And inside styles.js:

```js
 // ...

addIconWrapper: {
    width: '20%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  addIconBackground: {
    marginTop: -30,
    backgroundColor: '#85c349',
    borderColor: 'white',
    shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
    shadowColor: '#999',
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 1000,
    width: 42,
    height: 42,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  addIconImage: {
    tintColor: 'white',
  },
```

### Final result

[image: Final Result]

Comment: Thanks much, I could not find this answer for a while!